# EF6 inserting "\n" in query?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mariadb

Recently I discovered the beauty of Entity Framework 6 and decided to implement it in my current project. However, I stumbled upon a weird problem today. I have been searching the internet for hours, but I did not come to any solution yet.

First, some info which might be of use;

- We are using MariaDB for our database.
- We are using the MySql provider for EF6.
- The connection made is local and is working. The database correctly responds to correct queries in my application.

**The problem:** For some reason, EF is generating a query containing "\n". Since my error goes as follows;

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT\n`table`.`column1`, \n`table`.`column2`, \n`table`.`column3` at line 1"

I literally copied the query in my database interface (which is HeidiSql, for those who are interested) and after I remove the "\n", the query seems to work fine.

The error is thrown at:

```
using(var db = new DataContext())
{
   table tab = new table
   {
      column1 = "Some value",
      column2 = "Some other value",
      column3 = "Yet, another value"
   };
   db.table.Add(tab);
   db.SaveChanges();      //This is where the error occurs
}
```

I have debugged the input and it is correct. Also, the table is correctly added to the table entity. The code also compiles like it should.

Strange thing is, this is the only place where the error occurs (yet - I have to test it more to be sure of that). I call `db.SaveChanges()` in other places and somehow it does not throw any error there. In other words; I am actually able to add and save data to the database for other, more complex tables. This one, somehow, does not seem to work.

The table does not contain any primary or foreign keys (it really doesn't need any either, I've thought about it.).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "For some reason, EF is generating a query containing "\n". Since my error goes as follows" can you provide the code where the query is being generated?

Comment: No, I can't. It is generated within `db.SaveChanges()` which is internal. I already tried to access it and then filter it out by hand, but I can't seem to read it..

Comment: you said you have no PK. AFAIK, this is not possible with EF.

Comment: I will try to add it and see if the problem is resolved. I do not get any warnings/messages saying that I should have it, and don't you think the thrown error is a bit weird if this would be the problem?

Comment: The error is being thrown at db.SaveChanges() because that's when the query is actually (attempted) to be persisted, Getting an idea of your model classes and the actual assignment to model that produced your query "SELECT\ntable.column1, \ntable.column2, \ntable.column3" is important.

Comment: @Kritner The query is produced right there, by EF. I did not put it anywhere in the code, if that's what you're asking. It is completely out of my control.

Comment: @tschmit007 Apparently, it was the PK. Still a weird error though. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF you can't have a mapped entity without defining a PK.